# How to use Includes with activerecord associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

given two models:

```
User
  has_many :group_members
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_members

GroupMember
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user

Group
  has_many :group_members
  has_many :users, :through => :group_members
  has_many :group_invites

GroupInvite
  belongs_to :user
```

Thanks to Rails, I can easily get all of a user's groups with:

groups = current_user.groups

I then take this list of groups and iterate through to create a JSON object like so:

```
groups.each do |group|
  ....
  group.group_members.count
  group.invites.first_code
```

etc etc . The problem is this results in a large number of queries because I haven't found a way to use includes(:) to query for all the group_members and invites for all the groups with one query versus a query for every each loop. Any suggestions on how you can use includes like so:

```
current_user.groups.includes(:group_members, :invites) ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
GroupMember
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user

Group
  has_many :group_members
  has_many :users, :through => :group_members
  has_many :invites, :
  has_many :invitees, :through => :invites, :source => :user

Invite
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
```

Now you can:

```
current_user.groups.includes(:invitees)
```

Comment: Seems to be having no effect. I noticed that if I chance the include => to nonsense it doesn't even break?